# Type error unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' while performing stats.ttest_ind

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, statsmodels

I have dataframe that looks like:

```
  df:
  colA      colB
  A         0.97
  A         0.67
  A         0.32
  B         0.98
  B         0.81
```

`t,p= stats.ttest_ind(group["colA"],group["colB"])`

It throws an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int

Answer (score 3):

## The problem

The description of [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind` from the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html):

> Calculate the T-test for the means of two independent samples of scores.

The problem you're running into is that while the values in `'colB'` are indeed a valid example of possible "scores", the values in `'colA'` are not: they're just letters. There's no way you can do a t-test between a group of numbers and a group of letters. They're just not comparable like that. Internally, `ttest_ind` at some point attempts to divide the values in `'colA'` by the values in `'colB'`, which causes the error.

## The solution

If your values in the first column are meant to represent success and failure, then you're in a situation where one of your groups is binary valued while the other is continuously valued. In these kinds of cases, a more appropriate approach is to perform a [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). You would then get your p value using the [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test). If the values in the first column represent a categorical variable, you would do a [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) instead.

First you'd convert your first column in your dataframe to ones and zeros. Given that `A` is success and `B` is failure, here's how you perform the conversion:

```
df['colA'] = df['colA'].replace({'A':1, 'B':0})
```

You'll have to install the `statsmodels` package for this next part (if you have `pip`, just run `pip install statsmodels`), but the package makes it super easy to perform a logistic regression. You should consult the [`statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html#statsmodels-discrete-discrete-model-logit) docs if you have any questions about how to use it.

Here's a basic example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
df['intercept'] = 1.0

logit_model=sm.Logit(df['colA'], df[df.columns[1:]])
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

you'll then get an output like:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.528480
         Iterations 7
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                   colA   No. Observations:                    5
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                        3
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            1
Date:                Tue, 18 Dec 2018   Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.2148
Time:                        11:10:54   Log-Likelihood:                -2.6424
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -3.3651
                                        LLR p-value:                    0.2293
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
colB          -6.1702      6.722     -0.918      0.359     -19.345       7.004
intercept      5.3452      5.791      0.923      0.356      -6.005      16.695
==============================================================================
```

Not a very good p value, but there's only 5 datapoints, so that's what you'd expect. Assuming there's much more data in your real dataframe, you'll likely get better results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get what you are trying to say can u suggest me right appraoch?

Comment: I want to statistically see weather category of Method has any impact on the success

Comment: You probably don't want a t-test. I'll suggest something in the answer.

Comment: The colA doest indicate boolean, they are categorial values where I may have more than 2 categorial values

Comment: Also, can you pls indicate what is x1     in the output

Comment: A much better site for your stats-focused questions would [Crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). You'll be much more likely to get good answers to stats questions than you would be here.

Comment: Code throws an error saying "endog must be unit interval"

Comment: This is way off topic for the question you actually asked. If you have more problems, start more question threads. The short answer is to use [`sm.MNLogit`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.MNLogit.html), the multinomial version of the model.

Comment: This worked fine now, but I did not get p value for every unique value of  'colA' ie I have four categories of colA ie A, B, C, D then I wanted to have p-values for every unique category , but this doesnt seem to do so

Comment: The confidence interval set by default is 0.025, how can I change it to 0.05??  @tel